# Spark backward compatibility 1.6 vs 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark 1.4 code and now we plan to move to spark 2.0, and when I check the documentation below, there are only a few features that are backward compatible, does that mean I have change most of my code ?

> One of the largest changes in Spark 2.0 is the new updated APIs:
>
> - Unifying DataFrame and Dataset: In Scala and Java, DataFrame and Dataset have been unified, i.e. DataFrame is just a type alias for
>     Dataset of Row. In Python and R, given the lack of type safety,
>     DataFrame is the main programming interface.
> - **SparkSession: new entry point that replaces the old SQLContext and HiveContext for DataFrame and Dataset APIs**. **SQLContext and
>     HiveContext are kept for backward compatibility.**
> - A new, streamlined configuration API for SparkSession
> - Simpler, more performant accumulator API
> - A new, improved Aggregator API for typed aggregation in Datasets

Comment: *does that mean I have change most of my code* -- Well, you just read the documentation, it seems, so yes.

Comment: @T.Gawęda I'm not sure that I get the OP's question. There is a migration guide to spark. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#migration-guide

Comment: @eliasah I understand it as "Will I be forced to rewrite much of my code  to get it working on Spark 2". Migration guide is very good reference, post answer with it :) Answer of course will be "it depends", but more precise :P

Comment: Thanks @T.Gawęda. I have posted a quick answer.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the comments, Spark has a migration guide to follow. You can check it [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#migration-guide).

There is not much changes between 1.6 and 2.0 excepted what's cited in the document.

And to answer the question, I'd also say "it depends".

e.g Recently I had to migrate a machine learning application from 1.6.3 to 2.0.2 and the only change that I had to do where listed in the MLLib [migration guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#migration-guide).